# No member in framework target: Swift class as forward class in ObjC, accessed in Swift through ObjC class

Tags: swift, objective-c, dynamic-frameworks

So I am creating an ObjC framework which has mix of ObjC and Swift code: UtilitiesFramework.

Here is my StringUtilities class in Swift:

```
@objc 
public class StringUtilities: NSObject { }
```

I am accessing StringUtilities class in Utilities which is an ObjC class.

Here is Utilities.h which is returning StringUtilities and has a forward class declaration for same:

```
@class StringUtilities; // Forward Declaration

@interface Utilities: NSObject
- (StringUtilities *)stringUtilities;
@end
```

Here is Utilities.m which imports generated swift header file:

```
#import <UtilitiesFramework/UtilitiesFramework-Swift.h> // This should provide concrete implementation of StringUtilities

@implementation Utilities
- (StringUtilities *)stringUtilities {
   return [StringUtilities new];
}
@end
```

I am exposing Utilites.h file to Swift through module.modulemap:

```
module PrivateObjC {
header "Utilities.h"
}
```

I have set the import path accurately in build settings as:
`$(SRCROOT)/$(PRODUCT_NAME)`

Now when I try to access Utilities class in some other swift class it just compiles fine:

```
import PrivateObjC

class SomeOperations {
func doSomething() {
  _ = Utilities() // This compiles fine
}
```

However when I try to access the StringUtilities through its method, it gives compilation error:

```
import PrivateObjC

class SomeOperations {
func doSomething() {
  _ = Utilities().stringUtilities() // This gives compilation error
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
value of type Utilities has no member stringUtilities: _ = Utilities().stringUtilities()
note: method stringUtilities not imported
- (StringUtilities *)stringUtilities
^
note: return type not imported
- (StringUtilities *)stringUtilities
^
note: interface StringUtilities is incomplete
- (StringUtilities *)stringUtilities
^
note: interface StringUtilites forward declared here
@class StringUtilities
```

I thought this scenario is fixed as part of proposal:

[# 0384-importing-forward-declared-objc-interfaces-and-protocols.md](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0384-importing-forward-declared-objc-interfaces-and-protocols.md)

However it is not working for me. May be it is due to it being approved as part of Swift 5.9, whereas in my machine 5.8.1 is used or am I missing anything else over here?

How can I make it work in older versions of Swift? Any suggestions?